# Junit 5.5.1 and 5.5.2 suddenly failing to run tests: "Process finished with exit code -1"; 5.6.0-RC1 is missing a class

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I added Junit 5.5.1 to a project that otherwise uses 4.11. I've written tests that, until today, were running just fine. Today all the tests were failing with exit code -1 even before any of the test class was executed.  I'm not aware of any dependencies changing that would cause this.

I switched to 5.6.0-RC1, which seemed to be missing an extension class (TestInstancePreDestroyCallback).

I then tried noticed 5.5.2 and switched to it: it had the same problem as 5.5.1.

I gave 5.6.0-RC1 one more try - this time I noticed that the jar was named 5.6.0-M1.  This version worked, so I seem to be okay, but that was an unsettling and not-confidence-inspiring sequence of events.

My question is: has this happened to anyone else, and what exactly was it?

Update:  Turns out the class missing in 5.6.0-M1 is present in 5.6.0-RC1, so I've switched to it.  I'm not pursuing the 5.5.* problems any further.

Comment: Please show your dependencies (Gradle or Maven files) as well as the exact error message you get. At first glance it’s more likely to be a compile/build problem than a JUnit one.

Comment: I'm afraid my company considers dependencies proprietary. But here are details on the 5.6.0 issue:


`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstancePreDestroyCallback`


It's not in the M1 jar:

`$ jar tf junit-jupiter-api-5.6.0-M1.jar | grep "api/extension/TestInstance"
org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstanceFactory.class
org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstances.class
org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstanceFactoryContext.class
org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstancePostProcessor.class`


but it is present in 5.6.0-RC1.

Comment: Since 5.6.0-RC1 is working for me, I will not pursue the 5.5.*  sudden abort problem and I would recommend updating to the release candidate.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was getting this error because I had included both in my Spring Boot Application

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I removed the latter and it worked fine for me.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. I ended up going to 5.6.1 "cleaning" everything and it finally worked. It was kind of weird.

Answer (score 3):

I was pulling my hair out with this problem.  At first, I was missing this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but even though I had all the correct dependencies, it didn't fix this error.  Finally, I decided to, in intelliJ, invalidate the caches and restart (File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart) and it worked.  Not sure what the heck was going on, but that was my solution.

Ultimately, here are my JUnit/Mockito dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was jupiter dependencies.

You should have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

or:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```